# Close current browser window or tab when popup opens

Tags: asp.net, extjs, popup

So, I've seen this approach on one site (I can't remember it, though) and it works like this:

First, there is a simple page with a simple login form. But when you click the login button of the form, if the validation of user and password is positive and the response from the server is positive as well, a new pop-up window appears (which contains the application written in javascript - [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)) and the current tab of the browser (which was the login form page) closes.

In my opinion, this is an excellent approach because the `ExtJS` is a single page application pattern, powerful enough to run full `AJAX`, without visible redirects. Plus, the pop-up scenario eliminates the browser page control buttons (back, forward, refresh) and the address bar is read-only.

Now, I'm trying to reproduce this by using the help of ASP.NET as server side scripting language, among ExtJS as the main application. So, the results would be as following:

1. Login page with a login form - HTML5 + CSS3
2. Application page (pop-up window) - purely ExtJS
3. A web service - [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/)

The web service exposes the method for login purpose, as well as the other methods, and it always returns `JSON` responses. A session variable must be set (if the login was successful) before opening the pop-up and closing the window.

And here comes the question:

**How can I accomplish this scenario of opening a pop-up and closing the current window/tab if the login was successful?** Any help, hints, references, advices, criticism is totally what I'm expecting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to close the current window after open another one.

```
window.open('new window url'); window.close();
```

I tried this on my box, and it works well on chrome and safari

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.open('popop.html'); window.close();" value="open" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is the window does not open in pop-up, therefore the browser control buttons are still there. In ``Firefox 14.0.1`` it opens a new tab and it does not close the current one. In ``Internet Explorer 9`` it asks for closing confirmation and in ``Opera 11.64`` works like in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Edit: It's not working properly in ``Opera 12.01`` as well. It behaves just like in ``Firefox 14.0.1``

Comment: you don't want to have browser control button?

Comment: btw, what's the different between doing a redirct to the "new page" and open a popup of "new page" and close the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Keep away from opening pop-ups if you really don't have to. All modern browsers are set up to prevent you from opening pop-up windows by default.

AFAIK the only 100% scenario to open a new window (with target attribute) is a hyperlink clicked by user.
`window.open()` and even `document.getElementById("hiddenLink").click()` are blocked by certain browsers.

Are there any real positives of doing so or is it only a false novelty of that site? The reasons you state are all well with one-window scenario.

Comment: Yes, there are. One big advantage would be that in a pop-up the address bar is read-only, which me gusta. Why? Because, AFAIK, the client user cannot change the location (I mean, the address) of the website to another. This will prevent any ajax call or statement not being ended properly, etc. The only thing I have to worry about is catching the close event of the window to do some cleaning if the user skips the log out procedure. The back and forward buttons are useless here (it's a Single Page App) and the refresh shortcuts could be catch and ignored.

Comment: @CosminT.: Having a read-only address bar can be desired in some scenarios, I agree. Provided your page is running in its own window.
The rest of the reasons is questionable. Are you solving the right problem?

Comment: Is your goal to have:
A. a one page application, or
B. a two windows application

A. is easily doable using e.g. UpdatePanel without fiddling with new windows etc. There are good reasons for browsers behaving that way (security mostly) and going against can be pain. And users are used the web works this way too.
B. is and will be problematic AFAIK.

The decision is yours, I'm just trying to help.